How to create a table of contents with two columns for a document using the paracol package with two columns?
I have a document
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside,openany]{book}
\usepackage[left=2cm, right=2cm, top=2cm, bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{paracol}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}
    \tableofcontents
\chapter{Test}
\begin{paracol}{2}
    \begin{enumerate}[label=\textbf{\arabic*.}, start=1, nosep,leftmargin=0pt,labelwidth=*,itemindent=\parindent,align=left]
        \section{What does the word of God have to say about young people?}  \switchcolumn
    \section{QUE DIT LA PAROLE DE DIEU SUR LES JEUNES ?}  \switchcolumn*        
\item Christ is alive! He is our hope, and in a wonderful way he brings youth to our world, and everything he touches becomes young, new, full of life. The very first words, then, that I would like to say to every young Christian are these: Christ is alive and he wants you to be alive!  \switchcolumn
\item Il vit, le Christ, notre espérance et il est la plus belle jeunesse de ce monde. Tout ce qu’il touche devient jeune, devient nouveau, se remplit de vie. Les premières paroles que je voudrais adresser à chacun des jeunes chrétiens sont donc : Il vit et il te veut vivant !  \switchcolumn*
\item He is in you, he is with you and he never abandons you. However far you may wander, he is always there, the Risen One. He calls you and he waits for you to return to him and start over again. When you feel you are growing old out of sorrow, resentment or fear, doubt or failure, he will always be there to restore your strength and your hope.  \switchcolumn
\item Il est en toi, il est avec toi et jamais ne t’abandonne. Tu as beau t’éloigner, le Ressuscité est là, t’appelant et t’attendant pour recommencer. Quand tu te sens vieilli par la tristesse, les rancœurs, les peurs, les doutes ou les échecs, il sera toujours là pour te redonner force et espérance.  \switchcolumn*
\section{Jesus, ever young} \switchcolumn
\section{JÉSUS-CHRIST TOUJOURS JEUNE} \switchcolumn*
\end{enumerate}
\end{paracol}
\end{document}

Contents is

How to create a table of contents with two columns for a document using the paracol package, with one column in English and the other in French?

Looking at the aux file, there is no distinction between which column the \section etc.  appeared in.  You would need to create two sets of file extensions (e.g. toc0 and toc1) and use separate \@starttoc commands.  You would have to modify \section etc to use these names instead of toc.

BTW, you would probably be better off using \paragraph instead of enumerate and \item.

Rather than figure out what precisely you are doing wrong with enumerate, I simply removed all the options.  Also, there are problems using enumerate with paracol.
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside,openany]{book}
\usepackage[left=2cm, right=2cm, top=2cm, bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{paracol}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\globalcounter{chapter}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\tableofcontents}{\section*{\contentsname\@mkboth{% removed twocolumn test
     \MakeUppercase\contentsname}{\MakeUppercase\contentsname}}%
  \@starttoc{toc\thecolumn}}
\patchcmd{\@sect}{\addcontentsline{toc}}{\addcontentsline{toc\thecolumn}}{}{FAILED}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{paracol}{2}
  \tableofcontents
  \switchcolumn
  \tableofcontents
\end{paracol}

\chapter{Test}
\begin{enumerate}%[label=\textbf{\arabic*.}, start=1, nosep,leftmargin=0pt,labelwidth=*,itemindent=\parindent,align=left]

\begin{paracol}{2}
    \section{What does the word of God have to say about young people?}  \switchcolumn
    \section{QUE DIT LA PAROLE DE DIEU SUR LES JEUNES ?}  \switchcolumn*        
\item Christ is alive! He is our hope, and in a wonderful way he brings youth to our world, and everything he touches becomes young, new, full of life. The very first words, then, that I would like to say to every young Christian are these: Christ is alive and he wants you to be alive!  \switchcolumn
\item Il vit, le Christ, notre espérance et il est la plus belle jeunesse de ce monde. Tout ce qu’il touche devient jeune, devient nouveau, se remplit de vie. Les premières paroles que je voudrais adresser à chacun des jeunes chrétiens sont donc : Il vit et il te veut vivant !  \switchcolumn*
\item He is in you, he is with you and he never abandons you. However far you may wander, he is always there, the Risen One. He calls you and he waits for you to return to him and start over again. When you feel you are growing old out of sorrow, resentment or fear, doubt or failure, he will always be there to restore your strength and your hope.  \switchcolumn
\item Il est en toi, il est avec toi et jamais ne t’abandonne. Tu as beau t’éloigner, le Ressuscité est là, t’appelant et t’attendant pour recommencer. Quand tu te sens vieilli par la tristesse, les rancœurs, les peurs, les doutes ou les échecs, il sera toujours là pour te redonner force et espérance.  \switchcolumn*
\section{Jesus, ever young} \switchcolumn
\section{JÉSUS-CHRIST TOUJOURS JEUNE} \switchcolumn*
\end{paracol}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}



The original solution did not include chapters in the TOC.  Since \@starttoc does the entire TOC at a time, the only solution was to put the (one column) chapter entry into both columns.
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside,openany]{book}
\usepackage[left=2cm, right=2cm, top=2cm, bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{paracol}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\globalcounter{chapter}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\tableofcontents}{\section*{\contentsname\@mkboth{% removed twocolumn test
     \MakeUppercase\contentsname}{\MakeUppercase\contentsname}}%
  \@starttoc{toc\thecolumn}}
\patchcmd{\@sect}{\addcontentsline{toc}}{\addcontentsline{toc\thecolumn}}{}{FAILED}
\patchcmd{\@chapter}{\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\protect\numberline{\thechapter}#1}}%
 {\addcontentsline{toc0}{chapter}{\protect\numberline{\thechapter}#1}%
  \addcontentsline{toc1}{chapter}{\protect\numberline{\thechapter}#1}}{}{FAILED}

\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{paracol}{2}
  \tableofcontents
  \switchcolumn
  \tableofcontents
\end{paracol}

\chapter{Test}
\begin{enumerate}%[label=\textbf{\arabic*.}, start=1, nosep,leftmargin=0pt,labelwidth=*,itemindent=\parindent,align=left]

\begin{paracol}{2}
    \section{What does the word of God have to say about young people?}  \switchcolumn
    \section{QUE DIT LA PAROLE DE DIEU SUR LES JEUNES ?}  \switchcolumn*        
\item Christ is alive! He is our hope, and in a wonderful way he brings youth to our world, and everything he touches becomes young, new, full of life. The very first words, then, that I would like to say to every young Christian are these: Christ is alive and he wants you to be alive!  \switchcolumn
\item Il vit, le Christ, notre espérance et il est la plus belle jeunesse de ce monde. Tout ce qu’il touche devient jeune, devient nouveau, se remplit de vie. Les premières paroles que je voudrais adresser à chacun des jeunes chrétiens sont donc : Il vit et il te veut vivant !  \switchcolumn*
\item He is in you, he is with you and he never abandons you. However far you may wander, he is always there, the Risen One. He calls you and he waits for you to return to him and start over again. When you feel you are growing old out of sorrow, resentment or fear, doubt or failure, he will always be there to restore your strength and your hope.  \switchcolumn
\item Il est en toi, il est avec toi et jamais ne t’abandonne. Tu as beau t’éloigner, le Ressuscité est là, t’appelant et t’attendant pour recommencer. Quand tu te sens vieilli par la tristesse, les rancœurs, les peurs, les doutes ou les échecs, il sera toujours là pour te redonner force et espérance.  \switchcolumn*
\section{Jesus, ever young} \switchcolumn
\section{JÉSUS-CHRIST TOUJOURS JEUNE} \switchcolumn*
\end{paracol}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}



How can I use \pagestyle{fancy}?

Load the fancyhdr package.  Read the manual.
